# Review audit bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

When reviewing in the close vote queue I almost always start by clicking on the close button and then canceling that window, to see how the votes are standing on the question.

Because if I'm in the first 3 votes, I take more time to analyze the question. If there are already 4 votes for the same close reason I don't do such a "deep scan".

And if there are votes to close with different reasons, it is not unusual for me to skip that question: Because if my close reason will be in minority, but the question will be eventually closed, my nick will show up on the closed question banner as if I close voted the question with that specific majority reason, whereas I didn't do that, and I don't want the system to list my name for something I didn't know. (That could be considered a bug too, but I don't really care about this, since I can avoid it.) So I skip in these situations.

---

I didn't review for a week or so, today I had time to do some, and on the third question I got an audit question, which I started to handle as always: First clicking on the close button... To my surprise it immediately said that I failed the audit. ??? I didn't close voted anything, just clicked the close vote button, from where I should be able to back up.

This must be a bug, this can't be by design, or if it is, why is it so?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it is by design. Lemme go get the link.

Comment: Here's the relevant link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote This really bothers me as well. I wouldn't worry about it too much though, as long as you are paying attention  :-)

Comment: Wouldn't a better feature be to have a current 'status' on the question, so you don't have to press the Close vote button? I would find that useful also :)

Comment: @Seth I see this is a duplicate of that MSO question, but I don't see at that question that this is by design. It doesn't have the status-by-design tag, and the accepted answer also didn't say that it is by design, just that they can't correct this behaviour at that time. Also the statement in that answer, thath *"f you're clicking "close", you probably do want to close the question."* is totally wrong. But as this bug was reported half year ago on MSO and still not resolved I don't have much hope for a solution. :(

Comment: @falconer You're right, it doesn't *say* it is by design, I must have gotten it confused with another question (although Shog's word is almost as good as a tag). Don't give up hope yet, it takes a long time to get changes made to the system :)

Comment: I threw a lot of meta rep at that one ;) hope they change it.